# Почему программа выдает ошибку на Q_OBJECT в классе, наследованный от QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

Всем здравствуйте. Я недавно начал учить фреймворк Qt. Я писал программы на Qt наследованный от QWidget (для практики), а сейчас же уже учу QMainWindow (Главное Окно). Чтобы использовать сигналы и слоты я должен подключить Q_OBJECT, но почему-то он ругается на него. Если убрать Q_OBJECT - ошибка исчезает и программа компилируется без ошибок. Ошибки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Проверьте, что все функции, объявленные как слоты, имеют реализацию

2) Если это не поможет, запустите qmake вручную (в верхнем меню build -> run qmake)

Comment: Попробую, спасибо

Comment: Второй способ помог. Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: @Emmanuel слева в заголовке ответа есть стрелочка и галочка для этого

Comment: спасибо, не знал